# Connecting a domain-joined pc to a non-joined pc

Tags: windows-7, domain, windows-xp, remote-desktop, local-area-network

At my job we have a pc that controls the lights, ventilation, music,... of the factory hall. Since this pc runs on Windows XP it isn't connected to any network whatsoever. However, the production manager would like to be able to control this pc from his own pc in his office, preferably through remote desktop. I've looked around on how to do this, but can't seem to find a solution in which I don't have to join that pc to the domain.

Is it possible in any way to connect these two pc's together and keeping the one pc in and the other one out of the domain? It is possible for us to install a second networkport on the one pc and connect them directly with an ethernet cable.

The pc from the production manager runs on Windows 7 64bit, the control pc on Windows XP.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I am fully aware of the risk with Windows XP, but the domotica software requires a Windows version not newer dan XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it's possible. Connect the computer to the same physical network and give it an appropriate ip address configuration for that network. Then connect to it via RDP and use local credentials to log in (a username and password on this computer). None of this requires it to be joined to the domain.

Answer (score 1):

1. From a security standpoint it is not advisable to continue running a factory control PC with Windows XP except if you have a contract for continued support with Microsoft.
2. As long as that PC continues to run Windows XP and assuming you *don't* have contracted support for it from Microsoft, from a security standpoint it is not advisable to connect it to any other machine which is in turn, directly or indirectly, connected to the Internet.
3. That aside, there's nothing preventing you to connect the two PCs, either via an isolated network (eg. by installing a second NIC into the production manager's PC) or via a routed connection (preferrably protected by a firewall), and to control the control PC from the production manager's PC via RDP. Joining the control PC to the domain of the production manager's PC is not necessary for that.